# XSLT discard duplicates on multiple criteria

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-2.0

I have the following data structure and need to output the ids of every node with every combination of `v1` and `v2` exactly once,  where `v` equals `A`.

The nodes with ids `2,3,4,6,7` should be printed.

```
<root>
    <node>
        <v>A</v>
        <id>2</id>
        <v1>S</v1>
        <v2>S</v2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <v>A</v>
        <id>3</id>
        <v1>S</v1>
        <v2>S1</v2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <v>A</v>
        <id>4</id>
        <v1>S2</v1>
        <v2>S1</v2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <v>B</v>
        <id>5</id>
        <v1>S2</v1>
        <v2>S3</v2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <v>A</v>
        <id>6</id>
        <v1>S2</v1>
        <v2>S3</v2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <v>A</v>
        <id>7</id>
        <v1>S</v1>
        <v2>S3</v2>
    </node>
    <node>
        <v>A</v>
        <id>8</id>
        <v1>S</v1>
        <v2>S</v2>
    </node>
</root>
```

I tried using an `xsl:key`, however unfortunately only unique elements are printed (id=2 is missing)

Using `preceeding` as shown in the following does neither generated the desired result.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <!-- pos 1 -->
    <xsl:key name="keys" match="node" use="concat(v1, '|', v2, '|', v)"/>
    <!-- /pos 1 -->

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each select="node[v='A']">

            <!-- pos 1 -->
            <xsl:variable name="vDups" select="key('keys', concat(v1, '|', v2, '|', v))[not(generate-id() = generate-id(current()))]" />
            <xsl:if test="not($vDups)">
                <node>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current()/id"/>
                </node>
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- /pos 1 -->

            <!-- pos 2 -->
            <xsl:if test="not(preceding::node/v1=current()/v1 and preceding::node/v2 = current()/v2)">
                <node>
                    <xsl:value-of select="id" />
                </node>
            </xsl:if>
            <!-- /pos 2 -->

        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

How can I achieve the desired result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've tagged this XSLT 2.0, and have `version="2.0"` in your stylesheet, in which case you can make use of `xsl:for-each-group` to simplify your XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="root">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="node[v = 'A']" group-by="concat(v1, '|', v2)">
                <node>
                    <xsl:value-of select="id"/>
                </node>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: I had a feeling XSLT2 had a better option! You forgot the `v='A'` requirement though.

Comment: Thanks! I've amended my answer.

Comment: I don't get the pleasure of using XSLT2 much, can I just clarify something- what happens first, the grouping or the filtering on `[v = 'A']`? In other words, would it not group IDs 5 & 6 then create a group because at least one `v` in the group has `A`, or would it filter out id 5 first, then group what's left?

Comment: Thank you very much - this solution works just fine!

Comment: @Flynn1179 - The filtering in the select happens first, then the grouping.

Answer (score 1):

change your key

```
<xsl:key name="keys" match="node" use="concat(v1, '|', v2, '|', v)"/>
```

to

```
<xsl:key name="keys" match="node" use="concat(v1, '|', v2, '|', v[.='A'])"/>
```

then an identity template

```
<xsl:template match="node()|@*">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:copy> 
</xsl:template>
```

and a do-nothing template for the nodes that do not match the first occurence of a key

```
<xsl:template match="node[not(generate-id()=generate-id(key('keys', concat(v1, '|', v2, '|', v))[1]))]"/>
```

see it in action [here](http://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/94hvTyX).

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:key name="keys" match="node" use="concat(v1, '|', v2,'|',v)"/>

    <xsl:template match="node[v!='A']"/>

    <xsl:template match="node[generate-id()!=generate-id(key('keys', concat(v1,'|',v2,'|',v))[1])]"/>

    <xsl:template match="@* | node()" name="identity">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

This has one template that excludes anything that does not have `A` in the `v` element, and another which excludes any that's not the first of the given combination. I've included the identity template to output the remaining nodes as-is, but you can substitute this for any processing of `node` you need.

Disclaimer: This is an XSLT1 solution, a more efficient XSLT2 solution may exist.

Comment: Thanks for your help!